# Protected Sheet Warning On Any Edit

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

Hoping to get some help with Excel 2010.

I have three visible sheets.  On Workbook Open, vba password protects each of the three sheets.

Now, whenever I make a change to any *unlocked* cell in any sheet, I get 4 protected sheet warning pop-ups.  The one that says that the cells are locked and you have to unprotect to edit?  That's all well and good except that I am not editing locked cells.  I am editing unlocked cells in other sheets!

Has anyone had this experience?  I have played around and two of them can be attributed to each of two sheets.  That is to say, when I only protect the first sheet, I get no pop-ups, when I protect only the second, I get 2 and when I protect only the third, I get 2.

Taking out formulas hasn't made a difference.

Here is the code for the locking:

```
For Each wSheet In Worksheets

    wSheet.Unprotect Password:="JMP_DST_Lock"

    If wSheet.Visible = True Then
        wSheet.Protect Password:="JMP_DST_Lock", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
        wSheet.EnableOutlining = True
    End If

Next wSheet

ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="JMP_DST_Lock"
```

Thank you very much for any help.

EDIT:
Turns out the comboboxes are the reason for the error.  If the linked cells are locked, anytime the sheet calculates (any change when on automatic calculation) causes the warnings.  Now, I have code that unprotects the sheets on each combobox GotFocus, but aside from that, these are cropping up.

Is there a middle ground?  A way to keep the linked cells locked without these warnings popping up?  A way to make sure the comboboxes are hitting the linked cells except on selection?

Thank you!

Comment: Ken, sorry about the shouting.  Frustration coming through the keyboard.  You're right, shouldn't have done it.  Thank you for removing.  I am adding the code to the top to show you the locking.

Comment: Not sure if your EDIT is providing more information about the first question, or if you're asking another question. If it's the latter, you should start a new (separate) post to ask it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic seems wrong. You're unprotecting the sheet, then protecting visible sheets, and then protecting the entire workbook (in the last code line).

Try something like this instead (untested):

```
For Each wSheet In Worksheets
  If wSheet.Visible = True Then
    wSheet.Protect Password:="JMP_DST_Lock", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    wSheet.EnableOutlining = True
  End If
Next wSheet
```

If the workbook is saved with the sheets in protected state, change it to something like this instead:

```
For Each wSheet In Worksheets
  If wSheet.Visible = False Then
    wSheet.UnProtect Password:="JMP_DST_Lock"
  End If
Next wSheet
```

Comment: No idea why that fixes this particular issue, but it does!  Thank you very much, Ken.